# Snap.svg animation run multiple times ends with different values

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, snap.svg

I have a circle. I want to create a function that animates it from 1 scale to 0.8 and back to 1. What I currently have works, but when I invoke it several times in a row with little delay, the animations conflict and the circle ends up with a different (smaller) scale.

While doing all that scaling stuff, I want the circle to remain at its position. Also, I want the scaling to be done with an anchor point at the center of the circle. This is currently the case.

Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hdodov/9ou7hbum/).

Because of the above reasons, I get the circle's current transform:

```
var trans = elem.attr("transform");
```

reset its scale:

```
trans.totalMatrix.scale(1);
```

and apply it:

```
elem.attr({transform: trans});
```

Then, I `animate()` to the desired scale (`0.8` in this case) like so:

```
transform: "s" + scale + "," + scale + trans
```

and when that completes, I `animate()` back to the original transform with scale `1`:

```
transform: trans
```

---

After the animation is run several times, the circle ends up with a smaller scale. **Why?**

**Edit:**

The delay between the animations is **intentionally** smaller than the length of the animation itself. My question is how to make the animation work *despite* that.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem was that the value in your `setInterval()` was too short. You were restarting the animation before it was finished.

You can also simplify everything a little if you don't try and merge two transforms. Move the `translate()` to a parent group, and things are a little cleaner.

```js
var snapelem = Snap("svg");
circ = snapelem.select("#mycirc");

var bounce = function (elem, scale, duration) {

    elem.animate({
        transform: "s" + scale + "," + scale
    }, duration * 0.33, mina.easeout, function () {
        elem.animate({
            transform: "s1,1"
        }, duration * 0.67, mina.easein);
    });
};

var count = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    if (++count > 10) return;
    bounce(circ, 0.8, 500);
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>

<svg height="300px" width="500px">
  <g transform="translate(40 40)">
    <circle id="mycirc" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I know I'm restarting the animation before it has finished. I'm asking how I can make it work despite that. I want it to always end at scale `1`, no matter when it was played.

Comment: If you take my code and change the `setInterval` value back to 200, you will see that it ends at scale 1.

Comment: Hm, didn't notice that. However, the SVG I use live can't be altered, so the transform _must_ be on the `<circle>` is there a way I could make it work that way and _still_ end up at scale `1`? I.E. how do I make it work while preserving the initial transformations?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Snap well enough to answer that question easily.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the bounce and setInterval functions like this and It worked well. The setInterval time must be greater than 500ms (I used 550ms), and in the callback of animate function you shouldn't use the scale (0.8) again, you must return it to its default scale, which is 1:

```
var bounce = function (elem, scale, duration) {
    var trans = elem.attr("transform");
    trans.totalMatrix.scale(1);

    elem.attr({
        transform: trans
    });

    elem.animate({
        transform: "s" + scale + "," + scale + trans
    }, duration * 0.33, mina.easeout, function () {
        elem.animate({
            transform: "s" + 1 + "," + 1 + trans // I changed the scale to 1
        }, duration * 0.67, mina.easein);
    });
};

var count = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    if (++count > 10) return;
    bounce(circ, .8, 500);
}, 550); // I canged this to 550
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the initial transformation, otherwise with multiple animations on the same object, they will get confused (they will anyway). So firstly, you need to make sure the animations aren't overlapping. I see from the other comments, this is part of an example, so leaving that aside for the moment, but make sure that doesn't happen in live code :).

So you can store the transformation

```
var trans = circ.attr("transform");
```

Then pass it into the func

```
bounce(circ, 0.8, 500, trans);
```

And in the func, use that...

```
var bounce = function (elem, scale, duration, trans) {
....
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ou7hbum/1/)